# Importing project from Eclipse to Android Studio - Dependencies

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

On Eclipse I have one application as lib.
Then I have 10 more applications that import this lib.

When I'm programming, I do this on the lib project, so I run the application that import this lib. In the application project I just do especific developments.

The code is shared by all aplications.

How can I do this in Android Studio? Because I need to have just one code for all projects.

I've already imported my lib to Android Studio but I don't know how to link it to my application, having in mind that all changes in the lib needed to reflect the other projects (when I open it and compile again).

Thank you all!

---Edit:

My lib settings:

```
include ':actionbar'
include ':myMainLib'
```

My myMainLib Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':actionbar')
}
```

My Application settings:

```
include ':myApp'
include ':myLibProject:myMainLib'
project(':myLibProject:myMainLib').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../myLibProject/myMainLib')
```

My Application gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':myLibProject:myMainLib')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
}
```

Error message:

> Error:(22, 0) Project with path ':myLibProject:actionbar' could not be
>   found in project ':myApplication'.

When I clicked to check the error, it's open the lib Gradle.

The actionbar source is in the lib's root dir.

Comment: You need to add the location of actionbar to myMainLib settings like you added myMainLib to your application

Comment: The actionbar source code is together with the myMainLib, in the same project, but it's another module. Besides include it, like Im already doing, I need to point something else?

Comment: Can you compile just the lib?

Comment: Yes. It's compiling with no error.

Answer (score 0):

As you have the lib and your apps on your hard drive, you can configure Gradle to resolve the dependency from the local file system.

You have to add these lines to your `settings.gradle` file, to have the library project available:

```
include 'yourlib:lib'
project(':yourlib:lib').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../yourlib/lib')
```

This code assumes that both project folders are in the same folder. You can adjust the relative reference or change it to an absolute reference if that fits better for you.

Then you can add the dependency to your app's `build.gradle` file:

```
compile project(':yourlib:lib')
```

Comment: I've done this before, but without 'lib:', in both case I recieved a message 'Gradle projects sync failed.'. I think it isn't finding the lib.

Comment: yourlib is the name of the project, and lib is the module's name.

Comment: Thank you! It make much more sense to me now! But I still having one problem. The lib had other dependencies, and after include this lib I'm receving another error: Project with path ':actionbar' could not be found in project ':yourlib:lib'. I have to link the sub-dependencies too?

Comment: These dependencies have to be linked in the library's Gradle files. You can do it like you've done it for the app.

Comment: Glad that I could helped. If this solves your problem, please accept my answer.

Comment: I'm still needing help. My project includes the 'Z' lib, but the Z lib has other dependencies... When Im trying to run the app, an error occurs in the libs inside 'Z', I think it's something about a relative path. Because my lib Z had other dependencies and it's look like the project is looking for this dependencies in the project path.